# join two dataframe together

Tags: python, pandas

```
               total_purchase_amt
2013-07-01            22533121
2014-08-29           214114844
2014-08-30           183547267
2014-08-31           205369438

              total_purchase_amt
2014-08-31        2.016808e+08
2014-09-01        2.481354e+08
2014-09-02        2.626838e+08
2014-09-03        2.497276e+08
```

having two dataframe, I want to join them together，the result is like this:
the last row in first dataframe should be replaced by the first row of second
dataframe.

```
                   total_purchase_amt
2013-07-01            22533121
2014-08-29           214114844
2014-08-30           183547267
2014-08-31        2.016808e+08
2014-09-01        2.481354e+08
2014-09-02        2.626838e+08
2014-09-03        2.497276e+08
```

Comment: just remove the last entry and then join?

Comment: any way to remove more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first) with the other df combining with the first df, this will perserve the values in your other df and add the missing values from the first df:

```
In [49]:

df1.combine_first(df)
Out[49]:
            total_purchase_amt
2013-07-01            22533121
2014-08-29           214114844
2014-08-30           183547267
2014-08-31           201680800
2014-09-01           248135400
2014-09-02           262683800
2014-09-03           249727600
```